# Run single-row query for each hour in a given datetime range

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

My application runs an hourly analysis over a portion of my ever-changing dataset based on some heuristic function, and all partial updates are saved in a single large table. Thus, for every partition, analyses are triggered in irregular intervals.

When accessing data about a single partition, queries are generally highly performant. However, one of the newly requested features is charts, which show aggregate trends. For every hour in a given period, I need to aggregate the latest available data up to that point in time for each partition.

It's relatively simple to obtain aggregate data for any given time:

```
select
    max(t.timestamp) as analysis_timestamp,
    sum(t.column1) as aggregate1,
    sum(t.column2)/sum(t.column3) as aggregate2,
from (
    select max(id) as last_id, partition_key from my_table
    where timestamp < '2020-08-01 12:00:00' group by partition_key
) as latest
    left join my_table t on latest.last_id = t.id;
```

This returns a row with correct values for a timestamp set in the query:

```
 analysis_timestamp         | aggregate1        | aggregate2
----------------------------+-------------------+--------------------
 2020-08-01 11:35:24.138942 | 4529383.990000015 | 1.0644286969003778
```

I want to get multiple rows, one for each full hour used as a timestamp filter in the subquery for a range. For example, for a `2020-08-01 12:00:00` - `2020-08-02 12:00:00` range:

```
 analysis_timestamp         | aggregate1        | aggregate2
----------------------------+-------------------+--------------------
 2020-08-01 11:35:24.138942 | 4529383.990000015 | 1.0644286969003778
 2020-08-01 12:38:29.357938 | 4321691.210000011 | 1.0643205989383653
 2020-08-01 13:36:48.153008 | 4320697.810000006 | 1.064240032298849
 ...
 2020-08-02 10:43:17.777413 | 4320374.999999988 | 1.0644218979245774
 2020-08-02 11:41:55.142559 | 4321029.210000006 | 1.0644020500213083
```

I found that I can iterate over a timestamp range in a 1-hour granularity by doing

```
select timestamp_filter from generate_series(
    datetime_pl('2020-08-01', '12:00:00'),
    datetime_pl('2020-08-02', '12:00:00'),
    '1 hour'
) as timestamp_filter;
```

But I don't know how to use this `timestamp_filter` in the context of the above query. How can this be done? This query will be requested very infrequently, and its performance is not mission-critical, so denormalization for the sole purpose of optimizing for this use-case is not worth it.